# Serialized Array to Columns in Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, serialization

I have imported a .csv file and it contains a column with a serialized array in it.
How can I make 4 columns out of the array? I already tried somethings with regex and phpserialize package but I could not get it done.

This is how the columns looks:

```
forecast
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a:4:{s:5:"sunny";i:10;s:5:"rainy";i:70;s:8:"thundery";i:0;s:5:"snowy";i:20;}
```

Now i want that the whole column gets seperated in 4 colums like this:

```
sunny|rainy|thundery|snowy
--------------------------
10   |70   |0       |20
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your forecasts are saved as strings in your dataframe, then you can extract your desired values with a regex, then pivot the dataframe. Something like this should help get you started (I've added in a row with new values just to demonstrate):

```
>>> df
                                            forecast
0  'a:4:{s:5:"sunny";i:10;s:5:"rainy";i:70;s:8:"t...'
1  'a:4:{s:5:"sunny";i:20;s:5:"rainy";i:80;s:8:"t...'

df.forecast.str.extractall('"(?P<column>.*?)";i:(?P<value>\d+)').reset_index(level=0).pivot('level_0','column','value')
column  rainy snowy sunny thundery
level_0                           
0          70    20    10        0
1          80    10    20        5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I joined both tables with join() and it works!